# wxwidgets's mainloop() and boost::thread

Tags: boost, wxwidgets, boost-thread

In short I'm trying to implement a GUI to my networking app. Both of them have mainloop() so I'm trying to put them into separate threads and I'm using boost::thread for it.

```
    //standard initialization of boost::thread
    GuiThread.join();
    NetworkThread.join();
```

However, above crashes for some reason unknown. I'm searching for any way to do the same thing so any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Red.

EDIT:

I'm creating boost::thread GuiThread of the wxWidgets mainloop like so:

```
    boost::thread GuiThread = boost::thread ( boost::bind( &myAppClass::MainLoop(), this));
```

and Networkthread same way.

then i rewrite wxApp OnRun() function like so:

```
    int OnRun() {
            GuiThread.join();
            NetworkThread.join();
            return 0;
    }
```

when i run it ( in vs2010 ), it says: myApp.exe has triggered a breakpoint and if i press continue it stops showing the window, if i press break it shows me assembly.

Comment: Not enough information. What crashes, where crashes, how crashes...

Comment: are you sure it's legitimate to access wxwidgets gui from another thread? You'd better leave this gui loop in the main thead, and start another thread for network loop only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run wxWidgets main loop from the same thread that initialized the library. If you want to run it in a thread other than main, it means that you can't use the standard `IMPLEMENT_APP()` macro but must do the initialization yourself, e.g. by calling `wxEntry()` manually.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm kinda noob with wxWidgets. Can you give more info about calling wxEntry() and can I still keep my main class that handles networking and gui together or will i have to make class that will inherit wxThread for gui alone?

Comment: In the simplest case it's enough to literally just call [wxEntry()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__appinitterm.html#ga7d3eefb35631a5d8dfce97eb17340b21). And you don't need to use `wxThread` for this thread, actually it's better if you don't.